# Deleting last comment reveals design bug

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

In the image below there  are two answers. I commented on the top answer, then deleted my comment, thus deleting the last comment on the answer. After deleting the last answer a dotted line still shows above the comment section, but disappears upon refresh. The same applies to comments on questions as well.

[image]

Comment: [status:so-what]

Comment: I've got to admit you've got the "Attention to detail" down for someone calling himself "Web_Designer". :) But to call this a bug...mwah, not really.

Comment: Congratulations, you've given new meaning to the word "pedantry". ;)

Comment: @DanielFischer - Agree somewhat but I don't think people should be put off reporting minor issues such as this. The fix might be quite trivial and something that can be done next time that code is updated anyway.

Comment: Yeah, I was going to report this before...but since it goes away, meh.

Comment: @MartinSmith Sure, nothing against reporting. I was just indicating that I don't care a bit about this behaviour.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Added logic to hid the comments container when last comment on the post has been deleted.

Should be working in the next build.