# CSS bug regarding deleted comments

Tags: bug, comments, design

I recently asked a question on serverFault. This is the normal link, whereas the second one is the one I got via notifications, leading to a comment.

1. [Can Heartbleed cause a server to crash?](https://serverfault.com/questions/591641/can-heartbleed-cause-a-server-to-crash)
2. [Can Heartbleed cause a server to crash?](https://serverfault.com/questions/591641/can-heartbleed-cause-a-server-to-crash?noredirect=1#comment698982_591641)

The commands seems to have been removed by a moderator, at least I guess that's what happened.
Clicking the second one leads to a very minor CSS bug, at least it does for me: the dotted line for comments is visible:

[image: CSS bug for removed comments]

It seems like the element with id `comments-QUESTION_ID` is missing the `dno` class, with seems to be normally applied when there a now comments present.

Comment: Also, I think it would be less confusing when getting the notification and clicking on the link to at least get _something_, i.e. a statement saying "This comment has been deleted." Should I open another question for this, as it is more of a feature request?

Comment: Well, it's expanding the empty list so you see the border. As for having a message, it's indeed a pure feature request and not a bug so feel free to start new question for this. :)

Comment: Oops, [already exists](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/47180/152859). :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard Yes, I see the reason **why** this is happening, nonetheless I think this is a bug as it is not consistent behaviour.

Comment: Hmm, I think it is very related, but not quite the same. I mean, there were like 5 comments there and it would be super-weird to have 5 [comment deleted] messages there, wouldn't it?

Comment: Hmm... you got a point there. But if you do it for comments, better do it for answers as well when <10k user browse a direct link to a deleted answer.

Comment: Related: [Deleting last comment reveals design bug](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/165875), though in that case at least it went away after a refresh...not so here.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Isn't that already done? I think I always get a special "This question has been deleted page" and I am well below 10k.

Comment: @dirkk only when the parent question itself is deleted. If you have direct link to answer that is deleted, but its parent question is not deleted, you will just see all the other answers (if such answers exists) but not the linked answer itself. Nothing gets highlighted and you're clueless as for "where's that answer?"

Comment: @ShadowWizard Forget what I said, I confused question and answer in your statement... I should focus on this distinction on a Q&A site ;) You are obviously right and I do think it would be a useful feature. Will post a feature request

Comment: Added a new question here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230696/show-a-message-if-directly-accessing-a-deleted-answer-or-comment