# Show a message if directly accessing a deleted answer or comment

Tags: feature-request, deleted-answers, deleted-comments

Currently, if you access a deleted question you will get a short message informing you that the question has been deleted. However, if you click on a direct link to a deleted answer or comment (which you can get via notifications), nothing is displayed.

This is naturally quite confusing as you will get the message about a new answer or comment via notifications, click on the link and simply see nothing.

Therefore, I propose to display some sort of message to the user, informing her/him that the answer or question has been deleted. Note that this is different from always showing a deleted answer/comment, as I specifically request it in case you access the specific URL.

One example for a comment would be: [Can Heartbleed cause a server to crash?](https://serverfault.com/questions/591641/can-heartbleed-cause-a-server-to-crash?noredirect=1#comment698982_591641)

One example for a deleted answer is: [Can I use one model inside of a different model in CakePHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/980556/can-i-use-one-model-inside-of-a-different-model-in-cakephp/21109129?noredirect=1#21109129)

This question is related to [CSS bug regarding deleted comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230694/css-bug-regarding-deleted-comments),  but requests a feature to circumvent the problem altogether.

Comment: The Android app has a message "The answer wasn't found. It may have been deleted" when it isn't able to find the answer. I think it's a wonderful message to have.

Comment: @StevenV That sounds good. However, I wasn't even aware there is an app for SO... Seems like I am getting old

Comment: If the question is a spam then this feature will help the spam spread instead of removing it quickly... am I right?

Comment: @ArceusMaster0493 No, why should it? In what way would e.g. showing a message like "The answer wasn't found" spread spam?

Comment: @dirkk ahh I misunderstood your suggestion :P sorry

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257536/give-an-error-when-a-10k-user-tries-to-access-a-deleted-answer/257537#257537

Comment: There is this old request: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88589/show-warning-or-404-when-following-permalink-to-deleted-answer, but I am marking that as a dupe of this one despite that one being older because I kinda like the answers here better.

Comment: @54D Why do you think so?  This is just a simple usability tweak.  The spammer's message will not be displayed, but you get a better user experience because you understand what's going on.

Answer (score 12):

I'm not sure if a bounty will help in speeding up the 6 to 8 weeks it generally takes to implement stuff but until this gets implemented you might want to try this userscript to mimic the behaviour you're looking.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Check if comment and answer exist
// @namespace    http://meta.stackexchange.com/users/158100/rene
// @version      0.1
// @description  Show a message if the answer or comment in the hash of the url doesn't exist
// @author       rene
// @match        *://*.stackexchange.com/questions/*
// @match        *://stackoverflow.com/questions/*
// @match        *://serverfault.com/questions/*
// @match        *://askubuntu.com/questions/*
// @match        *://mathoverflow.net/questions/*
// @match        *://stackapps.com/questions/*
// @match        *://superuser.com/questions/*
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

(function ($, window) {

    var hash = $(window.location).attr('hash'),
        msg = $('<div></div>')
                    .css('background-color','#CCFFCC')
                    .css('align','center')
                    .css('padding', '10px')
                    .css('text-align', 'center')
                    .hide();

    function showMessage(jqsel, text) {
        if (jqsel.length === 0) {
            $('div#header').append(
                msg
                .text('The ' + text + ' is not found. It may have been deleted')
                .fadeIn(2000)
                .fadeOut(5000));
        }
    }

    if (hash.length > 0) {
        cleanHash = hash.substring(1);
        if (cleanHash.indexOf('comment') === 0) {
            ids = cleanHash.substring(7).split('_');
            showMessage($('div#comments-' + ids[1]).find('tr#comment-'+ ids[0]), 'comment');
        } else {
            if (Number.parseInt(cleanHash, 10) !== NaN) {
                showMessage($('div#answer-' + cleanHash), 'answer');
            }
        }
    }
}($ || unsafeWindow.$, window || unsafeWindow ));
```

This takes the hash of the url and tries to find it in the loaded DOM. If it doesn't find the comment or the answer it fadeIn a message in the header of the page and fadeOut after 5 seconds.

You can find this script also on [Stack Apps](https://stackapps.com/questions/7376/show-a-warning-message-for-a-deleted-answer-or-comment) where I will take bug reports and feature requests.

Comment: Confirmed still works as of May 2017. This is great!

Comment: Consider dropping this on http://stackapps.com and then throwing a link here and [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88589/show-warning-or-404-when-following-permalink-to-deleted-answer)

Answer (score 6):

This has not been implemented yet (three years after the feature request), today I submitted a feature request for this but was pointed to this one.

[*The below is from my own feature-request I submitted*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257536/give-an-error-when-a-10k-user-tries-to-access-a-deleted-answer)

Something like this:

[image]

The current issue is that if some user posts a link to the answer and the answer's deleted, other users may think (and indeed, this has happened to me) that the *question* is being referred to, and not the *answer*.

Example from today:

[image]

Although [SmokeDetector *did* explicitly mention *answer*](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/3515259#3515259), the action of [Madara Uchiha](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/166899/madara-uchiha) did confuse a couple of users, including myself. This would've been prevented if an error message showing the answer had been removed had been shown when attempting to visit it.

I know it's a tiny feature request, but I think it'd be a nice feature to have.

Comment: [More than two years!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88589/show-warning-or-404-when-following-permalink-to-deleted-answer)