# Give an error when a <10k user tries to access a deleted answer

Tags: feature-request, deleted-answers

I've been noticing an issue recently I (and other users) have tried to access deleted answers, only to get the question and no error message.

This behaviour is annoying, would it be possible to have some sort of error message when we try to access a deleted answer (and are <10k)?

Something like this:

[image]

The current issue is that if some user posts a link to the answer and the answer's deleted, other users may think (and indeed, this has happened to me) that the *question* is being referred to, and not the *answer*.

Example from today:

[image]

Although [SmokeDetector *did* explicitly mention *answer*](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/3515259#3515259), the action of [Madara Uchiha](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/166899/madara-uchiha) did confuse a couple of users, including myself. This would've been prevented if an error message showing the answer had been removed had been shown when attempting to visit it.

I know it's a tiny feature request, but I think it'd be a nice feature to have.

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ Noted, provided an answer to this feature request. Might try and stir up some activity on the dupe.

Comment: yep - you could answer it showing what happened in chat to provide more reason. BTW - can you accept the dupe to avoid another 2 people having to?

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ Already tried, it won't show me the options I normally have (doesn't show the close option, which I normally have [only on my own questions, since I obviously don't have the rep]).

Comment: There's no big blue button saying 'This solved my question' at the top??

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ Nope: http://puu.sh/i72UJ/5abd5ff664.png

Comment: hmm.. weird! oh well - other users will mark it as a dupe for you :)

Answer (score 1):

I changed Rene's code from the [duplicate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230696/show-a-message-if-directly-accessing-a-deleted-answer-or-comment) *slightly*, to be more in-line with SE's style.

Still, would be nice to have this implemented as a default stock feature of the SE engine:

[image]

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Check whether a comment or answer exists.
// @namespace    https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/158100/rene
// @version      0.2
// @description  Show a message if the answer or comment in the hash if the URL does not exist.
// @author       rene, made into SE's style by cybermonkey
// @match        *://*.stackexchange.com/questions/*
// @match        *://stackoverflow.com/questions/*
// @match        *://serverfault.com/questions/*
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

(function ($, window) {

var hash = $(window.location).attr('hash'),
    msg = $('<div></div>')
                .css('background-color','#C04848')
                .css('align','center')
                .css('padding', '10px')
                .css('text-align', 'center')
                .css('color', 'white')
                .hide();

function showMessage(jqsel, text) {
    if (jqsel.length === 0) {
        $('div#header').append(
            msg
            .text('The ' + text + ' you are trying to access has been deleted.')
            .fadeIn(1000)
            .fadeOut(3000));
    }
}

if (hash.length > 0) {
    cleanHash = hash.substring(1);
    if (cleanHash.indexOf('comment') === 0) {
        ids = cleanHash.substring(7).split('_');
        showMessage($('div#comments-' + ids[1]).find('tr#comment-'+ ids[0]), 'comment');
    } else {
        if (Number.parseInt(cleanHash, 10) !== NaN) {
            showMessage($('div#answer-' + cleanHash), 'answer');
        }
    }
}
}($ || unsafeWindow.$, window || unsafeWindow ));
```

Comment: ..and the reason for the downvote is...

Comment: I guess people prefer to have answers posted in one place, and not scattered around. (i.e. this answer better be posted on the original question)

Comment: @ShadowWizard I posted an answer with the alternative code which (in my opinion) better suits the SE design, and that in the original question that rene probably wouldn't appreciate it if I posted the code there.

Comment: MSE, like Stack Overflow, is not a personal help forum - OP does not have to like the given answer. Anyway, I did not downvote this, just sharing my ideas why it got downvoted and personally I justify this.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I know, I've been around for a while.