# Flagging a deleted answer results in a message saying I am flagging too quickly

Tags: bug, status-completed, flags, answers, deleted-answers

**Steps to reproduce:**

- Open two questions (with answers, in this case) in different tabs in the same browser
- Flag an answer to one (might not be needed, but it's what I did, so I'm including it)
- Someone else (might need a diamond for this) deletes an answer to the other
- Without reloading the second tab, try opening the flag dialog on the now deleted answer

**Environment:** Firefox 46.0.1 on up-to-date Windows 8.1.

**Actual result:** The UI responds with a message stating that I am opening the flag dialog too quickly.

**Expected behavior:** (A) The flag dialog should open, as happens after I reload the page and click "flag" again. Alternatively, (B) a message should be displayed saying that the answer is ineligible for flagging. If the user doesn't have the reputation necessary to see deleted posts, always do (B).

Something like this, shamelessly borrowed from [this answer by cybermonkey](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/257538/157730):

> [image]

Comment: Weird. When the answer is deleted you should see [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ZAvd9.png) in any other tab, right away. So the bug is that the banner didn't show up, letting you click the action links to begin with. (Since we should not be able to click the "flag", I don't think it's a bug worth fixing)

Comment: @ShadowWizard I don't know about that; if you have the reputation to see deleted posts, flagging a deleted post (for diamond moderator attention, in this case) is a perfectly valid thing to do. I added mention of the environment, just in case it's relevant. This may or may not be worth spending developer hours looking into, but it definitely happened to me an hour ago, and I tried to describe as accurately as possible what I did before it happened in the hopes that it will help someone at least reproduce the error.

Comment: This same behavior happened to me when I was working Triage. This is probably an issue that affects all types of posts, for all uses capable of flagging.

Comment: I got this message again on a spam question, but this time the popup only lasted for less than a second, and the menu came up so I could flag it as spam (although I think it was already deleted when I flagged it...) Don't know how I keep on accidentally making this happen...

Answer (score 5):

I believe we found the cause of this, please retry now. TL;DR is that our CDN automatically retried GET requests that returned a 500, which is why we saw it in our logs, but you don't see it on your side. We have now disabled that feature so the CDN won't generate a 2nd request.

More details (same root cause): https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/326737

Comment: It's hard to do a controlled test of this on my own, but I'd be happy to team up with someone (a moderator, developer or other employee with a diamond) in chat for an attempt. Ping me here or better yet invite me into a chat room to make arrangements.